# Ansible долго выполняет task setup

Tags: ansible

Периодически возникает проблема с `ansible-playbook`: очень долго "висит" на задаче setup. Подробный режим ничего внятного не сообщил:

```bash
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: dmitry
127.0.0.1 EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464268193.51-68811809432139 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464268193.51-68811809432139 `" )'
127.0.0.1 PUT /tmp/tmpD6mRtI TO /home/dmitry/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464268193.51-68811809432139/setup
127.0.0.1 EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/dmitry/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464268193.51-68811809432139/setup; rm -rf "/home/dmitry/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464268193.51-68811809432139/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

Сколько это занимает по времени точно не засекал, но где-то порядка 10-15 минут, дальше выполнение происходит в нормальном темпе.

Сталкивался ли кто с таким, как лечить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что это весьма похоже на очень частую проблему "очень долго тупит midnight commander при запуске" (проблема разрешения имён - в hosts не прописан ip для hostname) - и у вас что-то не то с разрешением имён хоста. Плюс за эту версию -- что имя хоста разрешилось в 127.0.0.1 судя по вашему выводу.

Больше никакой конкретики не подскажу: если направление решения задачи угадано верно - то нужно знать, как у вас устроена сеть на предприятии - какие DNS-сервера, DHCP-сервера, какое окружение и т.п.

Comment: cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       xxxxнеlocalhost 
127.0.1.1       xxxxxнеlocalhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Вот и вся "сеть на предприятии" ) Обычный ноут на линупсе...
P.S. Так и не понял, как делать переносы строк, сдаюсь...

Comment: Не хватает строки 127.0.0.1 hostname.localdomain в /etc/hosts

Comment: @A K Спасибо, добавил. Т.к. проблема возникает не постоянно, то проверить влияние не получается, но, надеюсь, проблема ушла полностью.